# Tutorial about how to write custom form fields in django?

Tags: django, django-forms, customization

Is there any good articles that explain custom form fields in django, not custom model fields? I couldn't find any through google.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Form fields are easy to customize:

```
class UpperCaseField(forms.CharField):
    def clean(self, value)
        try:
            return value.upper()
        except:
            raise ValidationError
```

basically you just create a class that inherits from the field that most resembles what you want, then rewrite the clean() method so that it returns the value you want. Here is another example:

```
class MyObjectField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    # in this case, 'value' is a string representing
    # the primary key of a MyObject
    def clean(self, value):
        try:
            return MyObject.objects.get(pk=value)
        except:
            raise ValidationError
```

custom *widgets* on the other hand, are a little more useful, but a little more hard to do because there are a few more methods that need to be written so that they work smoothly.

Comment: Thank you. I think I need to write a custom widget because I need to customize the rendering of the field.

Comment: Note: clean() is responsible for running to_python(), validate() and run_validators(). If you override clean() and don't implement these, you'll mess things up.

Comment: orokusaki is right, if you override clean(), you should at least call it's super implementation with `super(UpperCaseField, self).clean(value)`

Answer (score 17):

As always with open-source code, you'll learn a great deal by reading the source itself. See the `django.forms.fields` module to see how all the different form fields are defined - most of them are subclasses of others already, so you can just replicate that and change what you need.

Comment: A link to the latest source: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/fields.py

Answer (score 6):

It's not a tutorial, but django's docs talks about this a little:

> If the built-in Field classes don't
>   meet your needs, you can easily create
>   custom Field classes. To do this, just
>   create a subclass of
>   django.forms.Field. Its only
>   requirements are that it implement a
>   clean() method and that its `__init__()`
>   method accept the core arguments
>   mentioned above (required, label,
>   initial, widget, help_text).

You can read about the clean method and see an example [at the django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/).  Again, not a tutorial, but useful.

I find I am learning a lot by reading the code in some of the the django app projects that are available, such as [django-extensions](http://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions), which override the form fields and are good learning tools (for me, at least).  This can help get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I found these **tutorials** helpful:

- [Django custom form fields and widgets](https://www.webforefront.com/django/formcustomfieldsandwidgets.html)
- [Django forms I: Custom fields and widgets in detail](https://tothinkornottothink.com/post/10815277049/django-forms-i-custom-fields-and-widgets-in)

As you have already mentioned, the Django **documentation** has a section [How to create custom model fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-model-fields/) which unfortunalety deals **only with model fields**, and moreover, it is not very comprehensive.

As [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1527591/11875147) already recommended, you can read throught the **source code** of the `django.forms.fields` [module](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/forms/fields.py) to see how all the different form fields are defined, and this might help you learn how to define new ones.

You can also learn a lot from custom form field **examples** here on Stack Overflow, such as [Custom hidden field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76254669/11875147), [Custom password field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76254553/11875147), [Custom form field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76309053/11875147), and [Custom tag field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3470158/11875147).

*Note: I have added all good resources that I know of, if someone knows about other. Please let me know in the comments and I will add them.*