# Django Admin: Using a custom widget for only one model field

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin, django-widget

I have a [DateTimeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField) field in my model. I wanted to display it as a checkbox widget in the Django admin site. To do this, I created a custom form widget. However, I do not know how to use my custom widget for **only** this one field.

The [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides) explains how to use a custom widget for **all** fields of a certain type:

```
class StopAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.DateTimeField: {'widget': ApproveStopWidget }
    }
```

This is not granular enough though. I want to change it for only **one** field.

Comment: There is a clearer solution, using the Meta attribute, here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10293970

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Create a custom ModelForm for your ModelAdmin and add 'widgets' to its Meta class, like so:

```
class StopAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Stop
    widgets = {
      'field_name': ApproveStopWidget(),
    }
    fields = '__all__'

class StopAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  form = StopAdminForm
```

Done!

Documentation for this is sort of non-intuitively placed in the ModelForm docs, without any mention to it given in the admin docs. See: [Creating forms from models](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-field-types-or-widgets)

Comment: Unfortunately this only seems to work for the main "edit" page, and not on the list display, whereas `formfield_overrides` works for both.

Comment: And that warranted a downvote? Please take a moment to read "Vote Down" privilege description: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down. I'm pretty positive my answer doesn't qualify as "an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect".

Comment: There's a range of opinions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/112664/146243, http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/46590/146243, http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/46596/146243.

Comment: Starting with Django 1.8 you should add `fields = '__all__'` to `Meta`. Vide http://stackoverflow.com/a/28306347/1161025.

Comment: ... and `approve_ts` means what? then repeated in next answers. There is no such thing in Django source, either in topic's question.

Comment: I updated `approve_ts` to `field_name` . Seems to have been a copy-paste that didn't get genericised.

Answer (score 36):

After digging into the [admin](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin), [model field](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py) and [form field](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/forms/fields.py) code, I believe the only way to carry out what I want is by creating a custom model field:

### `models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from widgets import ApproveStopWidget

class ApproveStopModelField(models.DateTimeField):
    pass

class Stop(models.model):
    # Other fields
    approve_ts = ApproveStopModelField('Approve place', null=True, blank=True)
```

### `admin.py`

```
from widgets import ApproveStopWidget
from models import ApproveStopModelField

class StopAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        ApproveStopModelField: {'widget': ApproveStopWidget }
    }
```

It gets the job done.

For the time being, I'll leave the question unanswered because I have the habit of missing the obvious. Perhaps some Django smartypants has a better solution.

Comment: For those wondering how to integrate this with South, the line you would need for this example is:  
`from south.modelsinspector import add_introspection_rule
add_introspection_rules([], ["^appname\.models\.ApproveStopModelField"])`

Answer (score 30):

Override formfield_for_dbfield like thus:

```
class VehicleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ["name", "colour"]

    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'colour':
            kwargs['widget'] = ColourChooserWidget
        return super(VehicleAdmin, self).formfield_for_dbfield(db_field,**kwargs)
```

(credit to http://www.kryogenix.org/days/2008/03/28/overriding-a-single-field-in-the-django-admin-using-newforms-admin/ )

Comment: Nice. Adding a custom `ModelForm` for changing just a widget of one field seems like an overkill to me.

Comment: Just tried this in Django 1.11.5 and it worked perfectly. My model has multiple TextFields and in the Admin change form I needed some to be regular <textarea> elements and others to be TinyMCE rich text editors to accept HTML instead of plain text. The all or nothing 'formfield_overrides' wasn't useful in this scenario.

Answer (score 7):

Django's ModelAdmin.get_changelist_form(self, request, **kwargs) will do the trick for the case of list_editable

```
class StopAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Stop
    widgets = {
      'approve_ts': ApproveStopWidget(),
    }

class StopAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  form = StopAdminForm

  #just return the ModelForm class StopAdminForm
  def get_changelist_form(self, request, **kwargs):
        return StopAdminForm
```

Refer to [Django Official documentation on this topic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_changelist_form)

I hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

You can change the widget for only one field by assigning your widget to a field in a custom form and assigning the custom form to an admin as shown below:

```py
# "admin.py"

class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        widgets = {
          'price': PriceWidget(),
        }
        fields = '__all__'

@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ProductForm
```