# How to correctly integrate Filepicker.io, Django and S3

Tags: python, django, filepicker.io

I am making a Django app which allows users to upload pictures via the admin interface and then access the URL of those images via an API endpoint. On the admin interface, the user should be presented with the Filepicker.io widget (to enable drag and drop functionality, etc.) and the file should be uploaded to S3. I have already entered my S3 credentials into the Filpicker admin page of my account.

My question is how to bring all these elements together. Here the appropriate files from my project:

```
# models.py
from django.db import models
from django_filepicker.models import FPFileField

# Add field introspection for FPFileField 
# See http://south.aeracode.org/wiki/MyFieldsDontWork
from south.modelsinspector import add_introspection_rules
add_introspection_rules([], ["^django_filepicker\.models\.FPFileField"])

class Product(models.Model):
    product_logo = FPFileField(upload_to='uploads')
```

---

```
# forms.py
from django import forms
from django_filepicker.forms import FPFileField
from django_filepicker.widgets import FPFileWidget
from example.models import Product

class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.fields['product_logo'] = FPFileField(widget = FPFileWidget)
        super(ProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

---

```
# views.py
from django.http import HttpResponse
from example.models import Product
import json

def example_view():
    result = []
    products = Product.objects.all()
    for product in products:
        # I want the S3 URL here!
        result.append(product.product_logo.url)
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(result, indent=2))
```

My problems are:

1. The Django admin interface displays the normal Django FileField widget, whereas I want the FPFileWidget instead
2. I want the image files to upload to S3 (not the /media directory of my site)
3. I want to retrieve the S3 URLs not the /media/xxxx URLs.

For example, a typical response is currently this:

```
[
  "/media/uploads/fp-file", 
  "/media/uploads/fp-file_1", 
  "/media/uploads/fp-file_2", 
  "/media/uploads/fp-file_3", 
  "/media/uploads/fp-file_4", 
  "/media/uploads/fp-file_5"
]
```

But I want something like:

```
[
  "https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/XXXXXXXXX/TBtOcRSNyBAZZuNBFOpA_blah.png", 
  "https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/XXXXXXXXX/8ODleDuKRIOAglFs0sKl_etc.png", 
]
```

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to change `DEFAULT_STORAGE_BACKEND` to an `s3` storage backend. Please have a look at [amazon-S3 backend of `django-storages`](http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html).

For using `FPFileWidget` on admin panel, please have a look at [Django Admin: Using a custom widget for only one model field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176613/django-admin-using-a-custom-widget-for-only-one-model-field).

Changing these two settings should work for you.

Comment: Thanks! I've fixed problem 1. using your link. Will check out django-storages

Comment: Let me know if you face any other difficulty.

Comment: hey guys, @psjinx I have a question. I have already modified my DEFAULT_STORAGE_BACKEND but it seems like the file is uploaded to filepicker then s3, on the filepicker modal and on form submit. Is there a way to get associate the file on filepicker to the FPFileField of my model instead of uploading again to s3? Thanks in advance.

Comment: FPFileField does not store fpurl.

Comment: Please have a look at https://github.com/Filepicker/django-filepicker/blob/master/django_filepicker/middleware.py

URLFileMapperMiddleware gives you uploaded files in `request.FILES`, but you get actual urls also in `request.POST`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at FPUrlField, that should give you what you need. The current FP*Fields don't have admin interfaces, but would be happy to take a pull request if you want to contribute the code back

Comment: Thanks Brett. Now the url field of the FPFileField points to https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/XXXXXXXX which, although not pointing to S3, it's better than the files being uploaded to /media