# Django models and admin panel

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-orm

Hi guys I have this model

```
class Class1(models.Model):
    ....
    ctime = models.FloatField()  # I am storing date in timestamp here
    ....
```

Is it possible to display ctime field in admin panel not as float but as time field?

Comment: Why not declare the model field as DateField, when you are storing a timestamp there? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datefield

Comment: Because if i will declare this field DateField i will not be able store float timestamp here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides). You can override default widgets for model fields -

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin

# Import our custom widget and our model from where they're defined
from myapp.widgets import RichTextEditorWidget
from myapp.models import MyModel

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.TextField: {'widget': RichTextEditorWidget},
    }
```

Or, for a single model, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5263578/257944) -

```
class StopAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Stop
    widgets = {
      'approve_ts': ApproveStopWidget(),
    }

class StopAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  form = StopAdminForm
```

Check other answers in that question too.a