# customize select in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, customization

I have a model, one field of it is a ForeignKey, so i see select in django admin, is it possiable to customize labels of this select?

```
class Model(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    def __unicode__(self):
         return self.name

class Part(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    parent =  model.ForeignKey(Model)
    def __unicode__(self):
         return self.name
    def name_with_model(self):
         return self.name + ' ' + parent.name

class SmallPart(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    parent =  model.ForeignKey(Part)
```

when I add new SmallPart I see select tag with names of parts, I need to see name_with_model

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you mean the field label:

using code from:
[Django Admin - Overriding the widget of a custom form field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469979/django-admin-overriding-the-widget-of-a-custom-form-field/4466958#4466958)

```
# forms.py

from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin

class ProductAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['tags'].label = 'Custom Label'
```

Then, in your ModelAdmin object, you specify the form:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from models import Product
from forms import ProductAdminForm

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ProductAdminForm

admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
```

If you mean the labels in the select drop down:

Override the widget like in the answer above.

**edit:**

The default form field for a fk field is a model choice field. From the [`docs`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield)

> The **unicode** method of the model
>   will be called to generate string
>   representations of the objects for use
>   in the field's choices; to provide
>   customized representations, subclass
>   ModelChoiceField and override
>   label_from_instance. This method will
>   receive a model object, and should
>   return a string suitable for
>   representing it. For example:

```
class MyModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.name_with_model()
```

and then:

```
class SmallPartAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SmallPartAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['parent'] = MyModelChoiceField(queryset=Part.objects.all())
```

Comment: look's like you misunderstand me (my question wasn't clear), I need to update  <select><option value='123'>This label</option></select>

Comment: You can do this by overriding the widget. How are you modifying the values? Based on a function? Please post some code or clarify in your post. Thanks!