# How to make django-taggit admin text input field a bigger size?

Tags: django, django-taggit

As per the title, how do I tell the admin interface (admin.py) to use a custom size for the tags field of my model which is using django-taggit:

```
tags = TaggableManager()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Similar question to [Django Admin - Overriding the widget of a custom form field](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3469979).

However, you'll need to override any admin.widgets, for example, AdminTextareaWidget, so that the tags are display correctly. Otherwise the form field value will be displayed as

```
[<TaggedItem: Product object tagged with bar>, 
<TaggedItem: Product object tagged with foo>, 
<TaggedItem: Product object tagged with baz>]
```

Sample code to illustrate this.

```
#forms.py

from django import forms
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminTextareaWidget
from django.utils import six

from models import Product

from taggit.utils import edit_string_for_tags


class TaggitAdminTextareaWidget(AdminTextareaWidget):
    # taken from taggit.forms.TagWidget
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        if value is not None and not isinstance(value, six.string_types):
            value = edit_string_for_tags([o.tag for o in value.select_related("tag")])
        return super(TaggitAdminTextareaWidget, self).render(name, value, attrs)


class ProductAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        widgets = {
            'tags': TaggitAdminTextareaWidget
        }
```