# I resized the field, but now instead of tag names I see a list

Tags: python, django

I resized the field, but now instead of tag names I see a list.
How i can fix it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9p8u.png)

```
formfield_overrides = {
        TaggableManager: {'widget': AdminTextareaWidget(attrs={'rows': 4, 'cols': 40})},
        }
```

Comment: this happened after resizing?

Comment: something is wrong with your widget. refer to this link for more detail https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469979/django-admin-overriding-the-widget-of-a-custom-form-field . Also post your complete code. its impossible to understand from one line

Comment: @AtlasBravoos, yes, in this line i changed TaggableManager field to AdminTextareaField, because i need to resizing field, but TaggableManager not resizing and very small

Comment: try using a form as shown in the link above

Answer (score 0):

look at this  example

```
class ProjectAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'project_description': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 98})
        }
class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ProjectAdminForm
```