# django show admin field on demand

Tags: python, django

I'd like to hide fields on demand in the django admin interface, this means not all parameters are necessary. This is only for usability for the customers of my software.

If some condition is made, e.g. the type field should be *completely* hidden.

Condition not made:

[image]

Condition made (with my current code):

[image]

Hiding is possible, but there remain "leftovers". Is it possible to hide the "type line" complete without such leftovers? Like when

```
class Meta:
    exclude = ["type"]
```

is set? (This isn't possible to modify at runtime)

So far my code to hide the admin field on demand:

```
class SubItemForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SubItemForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance.type == "SOME CONDITION":
            self.fields["type"].widget = CompleteHidden()
            self.fields["type"].label = ""

    class Meta:
        model = SubItem
```

Comment: does it work? what is your question? you may also remove the field from the dict (self.fields.pop("type")) completely.

Comment: This raises sadly "Key 'type' not found in Form". My (inelegant) fallback option is using JavaScript to hide the regarding field.

Answer (score 0):

add editable=False to the field you want to hide in model class.

e.g.

```
to_hide = models.TextField(editable=False)
```

hope it helps.

Comment: Can I do this at runtime resp. separate on every instance?