# Change DateTImeField to hidden in django

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I have a django form with three fields. Two of them need to be enter by the user and store within my database. DateTimeField is generated automatically. When I display the form in my main page all the fields are there, How can keep DateTimeField hidden? [Here is a link with different approaches, but I did not help me.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862250/change-a-django-form-field-to-a-hidden-field)

Here is my code:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    body = models.TextField()
    dateCreated = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True, )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post #this is the name of the model
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
```

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    body = models.TextField()
    dateCreated = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True, )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Html Code

```
<form method="POST" action=""> {% csrf_token %}
{{form.as_p}}

<input type='submit' value='Join' class = 'btn'>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to show the `dateCreated` field in the form at all.  This is an internal data and shouldn't be exposed to the user:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'body', )
```

Answer (score 2):

[Just set a value for the forms `exclude` attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use):

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        exclude = ['dateCreated']
```