# Django saveing logged in logged in user as ForeignKey

Tags: django, foreign-keys, hidden-field

I have model with a ForeignKey "log_written_by" and I want that to be the logged in user.

How should i state that in my forms.py as a hiddenfield?

```
class AssetLog(models.Model):

    # Relationships
    log_written_by = models.ForeignKey("auth.User", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    asset_case = models.ForeignKey("asset_app.AssetCase", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # Fields
    date_time_log = models.DateTimeField()
    notes = models.TextField(max_length=1024)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)

    class Meta:
        pass

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pk)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("asset_app_AssetLog_detail", args=(self.pk,))

    def get_update_url(self):
        return reverse("asset_app_AssetLog_update", args=(self.pk,))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
class AssetLogForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AssetLog
        fields = ('log_written_by ', '...,')
        widgets = {'log_written_by ': forms.HiddenInput()}
```

See this related StackOverflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862250/change-a-django-form-field-to-a-hidden-field).