# How To Hide Form Fields When A Particular Type Of Product Is Selected Django

Tags: python, django

Please I have a project where I want to hide some fields in a form when the category selected belongs to a particular product type. The type of products is Single and Bundle products. So for instance, if I choose something like **pens(Bundle)** in the form category I should only see quantity in the form fields but if I select something like **Desk(single)** all fields should be available to fill. **How do I implement this in Django?** Thank you

**My Model**

```py
TYPE =(('Single', 'Single'),('Bundle','Bundle'))
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    pro_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=TYPE, null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'
```

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    pro_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default='0', blank=True, null=True)
    issue_to = models.ForeignKey('Order',default='', on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)
    serial_num = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    model_num = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    storage_size = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
```

**My views**

```py
def add_products(request):
    form =  ProductCreateForm(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.staff = request.user
            obj.save()
            return redirect('dashboard-products')
    else:
        form = ProductCreateForm()
    context = {
        'form': form,  
    }
```

Comment: You'd probably want to split this into two forms , one with category only and on next page render form for product. If you want to use same form for Product you can conditionally hide unneeded fields with: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6862413/10547647

Comment: Otherwise if you want it all on same page I think some JS code would be inevitable.

Comment: @Adam yes I want all on the same page. Do you have a js example for me