# Django password field custom class

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-auth-models

I would like to render the password field with a custom class, so I tried this:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db import transaction
User = get_user_model()

class SignupForm(forms.ModelForm):

    first_name = forms.CharField(label=_(u'First name'), max_length=30)
    last_name = forms.CharField(label=_(u'Last name'), max_length=30)
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget = forms.PasswordInput(render_value = True, attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Your password'}))


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Your username'})
        self.fields['first_name'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Your first name'})
        self.fields['last_name'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Your last name'})
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Your email address'})
        self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Your password'})
```

As you may notice, I tried to add the class on the declaration and in the initialization but none of this works. The class is still the default one.

Note that for email, username, and the other fields, the class/placeholder are working fine.
Am I missing something?

EDIT:
This will probably help in diagnosing the problem. This is what I use in HTML:

```
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <br />
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password1">{{ form.password1.label }}</label>  
                            {{ form.password1 }}    
                            {% if form.password1.errors %}
                                <div class="text-danger">{{ form.password1.errors|escape }}</div>   
                            {% endif %}                             
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Are you sure this is not a CSS issue? If you look at the source code of the page produced by the backend, does the password field contains the `form-control`?

Comment: No it's not containing neither the class not the placeholder

Comment: may be you provide another form to your html context, not this one

Comment: Since "first_name" placeholder/class changed according to my config, then I guess it should be the right form.

Comment: where is the inner class Meta: model=User fields=[...]

Comment: It's Profile. I didn't add it to my question, but it's Profile and it uses  OneToOne relation with User.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this directlly without the init method

```
 password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(
    attrs={'class':'form-control','type':'password', 'name': 'password','placeholder':'Password'}),
    label='')
```

Answer (score 0):

[Ngawang13's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62769030/11875147) solved the issue in the questions for me - i.e. the class was set to `form-control`.

However, to expand on Ngawang13's answer, if you wanted to use this field in multiple places, you **could create a custom field class**.

```
class MyCustomPasswordField(forms.CharField):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs,):
        self.widget = forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Password'})
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```