# Custom form field class with dynamic widget attributes

Tags: django, django-forms, django-custom-field

I often use Django form fields with various lengths. I would like to create a custom form field class `MyFloatField` with a dynamic widget attribute so I could set the `max_width` when defining each form field such as:

```
quantity = MyFloatField(label='Quantity:', max_width='50px')
price = MyFloatField(label='Price:', max_width='100px')
```

I have already created a custom form field where the `max_width` is a constant.

```
class MyFloatField(forms.FloatField):
    def widget_attrs(self, widget):
        attrs = super().widget_attrs(widget)
        attrs.setdefault("style", 'max-width: 50px')
        return attrs
```

I assume that in order to make it dynamic (pass the value from field definition) I need to somehow get the argument `max_width='100px'` from the definition of the form field and pass it as a variable to the `attrs.setdefault()`. I have tried the following but I get a `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_width'` error.

```
class MyFloatField(forms.FloatField):
    def widget_attrs(self, widget):
        my_max_width = kwargs['max_width']
        attrs = super().widget_attrs(widget)
        attrs.setdefault("style", 'max-width: '+my_max_width)
        return attrs
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close. If you want to use the value of your custom keyword argument `max_length` in the `widget_attrs()` function of an instance of the `MyFloatField()` class, you want to do the following.

You want to **assign the value** of the `max_length` argument **to the instance variable** `self.max_length` within the class's `__init__()` method. By storing the value of `max_length` as an instance variable, it becomes accessible throughout the class, and thus, can be referenced in the `widget_attrs()` function. The class should thus look like this:

```
class MyFloatField(forms.FloatField):
    def __init__(self, *, max_width='1000em', **kwargs):
        self.max_width_variable = max_width
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def widget_attrs(self, widget):
        my_max_width = self.max_width_variable
        attrs = super().widget_attrs(widget)
        attrs.setdefault("style", 'max-width: '+my_max_width)
        return attrs
```

Note that both `max_width_variable` and `my_max_width` variables could both be called the same as the keyword (i.e. `max_width`). I have given them different names just so you are clear which variable is which.